# taking pairs into parallel rather than series

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt that look like this having sets of data:

```
C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,,,,,
Layer_00 , 3.46ms,Layer_01 , 3.40ms,Layer_02 , 3.56ms,Layer_03 , 3.49ms,Layer_04 , 3.44ms
Layer_05 , 3.45ms,Layer_06 , 3.44ms,Layer_07 , 3.46ms,Layer_08 , 3.45ms,Layer_09 , 3.48ms
C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,,,,,
Layer_00 , 3.42ms,Layer_01 , 3.39ms,Layer_02 , 3.51ms,Layer_03 , 3.41ms,Layer_04 , 3.43ms
Layer_05 , 3.40ms,Layer_06 , 3.43ms,Layer_07 , 3.45ms,Layer_08 , 3.43ms,Layer_09 , 3.42ms
```

I used the below code to get the pairs:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    pairs = re.findall('(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', file.read())
pairs = [(k, float(v)) for k,v in pairs]
df = pd.DataFrame(pairs)
```

which give me the 2 data sets in series

[image]

however I want to have them to be in parallel:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it,

```
import pandas as pd

pairs_ = dict()

for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', text):
    pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values())
```

---

```
          0     1         2     3
0  Layer_00  3.46  Layer_00  3.42
1  Layer_01  3.40  Layer_01  3.39
2  Layer_02  3.56  Layer_02  3.51
3  Layer_03  3.49  Layer_03  3.41
4  Layer_04  3.44  Layer_04  3.43
5  Layer_05  3.45  Layer_05  3.40
6  Layer_06  3.44  Layer_06  3.43
7  Layer_07  3.46  Layer_07  3.45
8  Layer_08  3.45  Layer_08  3.43
9  Layer_09  3.48  Layer_09  3.42
```